# Laravel: Looping through Input data in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form which posts to my confirmation page, on this page the user is shown the details entered and requested to either 'Post' or Go Back.

I want to know how can I iterate through all of the post data items as hidden inputs without physically writing them for each post data item.

Here is my *confirm* method in my **controller** to show you how the data is passed:

```
public function confirm(Request $request)
{
    $input = $array = array_except(Request::all(), array('_token'));

    return view('jobs.confirm', compact($input));
}
```

Here is my confirmation **blade page**:

```
{{ Input::get('title') }}
{{ Input::get('description') }}

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'JobsController@store']) !!}
    @foreach (Input as $input)
    @endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My foreach loop doesn't work, can anyone explain how I can achieve the loop passing both key and value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't just loop over the class `Input`. Use `Input::all()` to get all items or work with the variable you're passing to the view.

Then, to get the key and the value, use the normal PHP foreach syntax:

```
@foreach($input as $name => $value)
```

And lastly, you obviously have to put something between the `@foreach` and the `@endforeach` tag.

For example:

```
@foreach($input as $name => $value)
    {{ $name }}: {{ $value }} <br/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Just needed that first line, I was aware that something needed to inside the loop